# API Gateway for Amzon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have my `Node` server running on `Amazon EC2`. I want to implement `API Gateway` in that. I have gone through the examples in `AWS Documentation`, they have provided examples only for `AWS Lambda`. Can someone tell me how to implement API Gateway for the server in EC2.

Answer (score 0):

- create your API Method.
- On the integration Request, go to integration type
- Select AWS Services.
- From the Dropdown select Amazon EC2.

Comment: Any reference link ?

Comment: Not really... I am currently creating an API using AWS API gateway as well but using AWS lambda function. I remember coming across this option of being able to choose EC2. Your best bet is to google it out.